# TextView inside a fragment isn't updating text visually

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to update a textView after a filter task and i'm having some problems with Samsung devices. Other devices are OK (Moto E, Moto G, LG Nexus 4 and 5).

While debugging the application with DDMS the textView text property is set correctly, but visually the text doesn't change.

It's a problem on Samsung devices or it's something wrong with my code?

```
public void showDropDownNav(final MenuItem item) {
    showCategories();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.prompt_mesg))
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            filterCategory = spinnerArrayAdapter.getTag(
                                    which).getCategoryId();

                            final String all = spinnerArrayAdapter.getTag(
                                    which).getCategoryTitle();

                            view.footerText.setText(all);
                            categoryDisplay = all;

                            if ((all != null)
                                    && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(all))
                                    && (all != getActivity().getString(
                                            R.string.all_categories))) {

                                mHandler.post(fetchReportListByCategory);

                            } else {
                                mHandler.post(fetchReportList);
                            }dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `view`?